# Ubuntu does not detect my USB connected phone

Tags: usb

I connected my phone using an USB cord to my desktop, but Ubuntu does not detect the phone.

How do i transfer files to and fro from my computer ?

Comment: Which phone ...?

Comment: @Rajeev Probably you must select mass storage mode in your Phone. If this solved the problem for you then you are kindly requested to remove your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Android:** Open notifications, and see if "USB Connected" is coming up. Tap on it. Then tap on "Turn on USB Storage". If any window comes up, tap OK. Wait for a while till logo changes to orange, Ubuntu-jealous Android robot.

**iPhone:** Bad luck. iTunes is your only way and there is no iTunes available for Linux. There is one way though; open Terminal and type these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ingo/ios7support
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Reboot your PC, and connect your iPhone again. Press "Trust" if a "Trust this PC" window comes up on your iPhone. It should appear like a hard drive/USB Storage device after this.

**Nokia Symbian/Cheap cell phones:** Connect to PC. See if connection mode window pops up on screen. Select Mass Storage.